# Why Mathematica doesn't give output for Integration of Special Function

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I am trying to Integrate the expression given below. But, everytime I am not able to integrate it. Tried a lot but it's not working. Please any suggestion will help me a lot.
I am trying to integrate with respect to r. All other characters are constants.

```
 r^4 ((56.2277 + m4 (151.875 - 204.375 r) - 49.4122 r) r + 
        m3 (102. - 160.75 r + 21.75 r^2) + 
        n3 (84. - 154.438 r + 70.6875 r^2) + (
        m2 (39. - 57. r - 12.375 r^2 + 10.875 r^3))/r + (
        n2 (69. - 61. r - 61.875 r^2 + 54.375 r^3))/r + (
        n1 (54. - 48. r - 43.3125 r^3 + 38.0625 r^4))/
        r^2 + (-23.9743 + 32.329 r - 10.1709 r^2) Hypergeometric2F1[
          0.267949, 3.73205, 4., 0.9 r])^2 + 
     r^8 (-117.567 + 25.875 m2 + 51.75 m3 + 32.625 m4 + 90.5625 n1 + 
        129.375 n2 + 168.188 n3 - (132. n1)/r^4 - (15. m2)/r^3 + (
        114. n1)/r^3 - (93. n2)/r^3 + (11. m2)/r^2 + (55. n2)/r^2 + 
        83.4896/r - (18.375 m2)/r - (40.75 m3)/r - (10.125 m4)/r - (
        64.3125 n1)/r - (91.875 n2)/r - (171.438 n3)/
        r + (-20.3418 + 32.329/r) Hypergeometric2F1[0.267949, 3.73205, 4.,
           0.9 r] + (7.27402 - 5.39422/r - 2.28846 r) Hypergeometric2F1[
          1.26795, 4.73205, 5., 0.9 r])^2
```

Comment: _All other characters are constants._ It would help if you provided their values.

Comment: Are you trying to find an anti-derivative or is it a definite integral over a range of `r`?

Comment: I expand your expression into a list of many terms. `expr=List@@Expand[YourExpression]` I try indefinite integration on each term. `Cases[Table[Integrate[expr[[i]],r],{i,Length[expr]}], a_*Integrate[b_,r]]` This shows it cannot integrate some terms and what those terms look like. Can you use this idea to identify where the problem is in your integration?

Comment: @flinty Thank you for trying it. I am trying to solve a problem using Least Square Method and these constants need to be solve which can be possible after this integration which is an error^2 (lhs-rhs)^2 of equilibrium equation. After getting this integration, I will differentiate this integration with each constant and then will solve Simultaneous equation to get the values of these constants.

Comment: @Bill. Thanks Bill for trying it. If you see the problem, it has two separate parts and each part is squared. If I don't square them, then I am able to integrate it. But, once I squared it, Mathematica couldn't integrate.

Comment: It seems I guessed your problem correctly. It appears that MMA does not know a closed form solution for `Integrate[Hypergeometric2F1[a,b,c,d*r]^2,r]` or for `Integrate[Hypergeometric2F1[a,b,c,d*r]*Hypergeometric2F1[e,f,g,h*r],r]` for constants a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h. Can you search any references for calculus and see if anyone knows a closed form solution for these integrals? Can you perhaps try the free Rubi integration tool with Mathematica and see if it knows a closed form solution? There may be no known closed form solution. Perhaps you can revise your question to make it moreclear what you need.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. Let me try these.

Comment: `Rubi integration tool ` can't help you because is `Math` problem.